# Узнать какой input text был заполнен

Tags: php, ajax, submit

Есть большое количество `input` ов, которые нужно отправить если совпадает `name` с `data-id` сабмита.
Вот `submit` и `input`ы :

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="1"  class="count-value" disabled size="1"/> 
<input type="text" value="0" name="2"  class="count-value" disabled size="1"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="3"  class="count-value" disabled size="1"/>
<a href="" data-id='1' class="submit-stat">ok</a>  
<a href="" data-id='2' class="submit-stat">ok</a>  
<a href="" data-id='3' class="submit-stat">ok</a>
```

ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit-stat").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {count: $('.count-value').val(), key: $(this).attr("data-id")},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.result-block').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: у вас совпадает по любому, поконкретней, нвдо отправлять только если кнопка нажата и инпут с ее name заполнен?

Comment: Надо отправить значение того `input`a, у которого `name = data-id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде не хватает двух ключевых моментов:

1. Определение data-id, который был кликнут
2. Определение по кликнутому data-id именно того поля данных, которое соответствует этому data-id

По шагам, чтобы в click() взять элемент, по которому кликнули, достаточно взять this:

```
var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

И второй шаг, нужно в AJAX отсылать не просто какой-то count, а именно нашего элемента с data-id. Меняем код

```
data: {count: $('.count-value').val(), key: $(this).attr("data-id")},
```

на более конкретный

```
data: {count: $('.count-value[name='+data_id+']').val(), key: $(this).attr("data-id")},
```

Так будет то, что нужно

Comment: у вас data-id в переменной уже, её тогда и слать надо, а не заново дёргать

Comment: Я только показал две точки, где человек должен поправить, чтобы у него заработало, и сфокусировал внимание на них. Уверен, что такие вещи он сможет и сам поправить )

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit-stat").click(function () {
            var val = $('.count-value[name='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').val();
            if (!val) {
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {count: val, key: $(this).attr("data-id")},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.result-block').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```